# Why does my CSS div class overwrite the image behind it?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` to encompass a whole partial view:

```
<div class="bkgImg">
    /* everything else in here */
</div>
```

within that `<div>` are two other `<div>`s, one without a class and one with a class:

```
<div>
        <h1>stuff</h1>
        <img class="img-rounded" src="~/Content/Images/blahblah.svg" />
        <p>stuff</p>
</div>

<div class="customRound">
    <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="unimportant">
                    Languages
                </a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

THe "bkgImg" shows up until the end of the first `div`, but because I've created a class for the 2nd div, it's coming up whitesmoke - the color I picked for the body. Why does choosing a class for the div override the encompassing parent `div` ??

I've tried putting background as "none" and "inherit" and `background:rgba(0,0,0,0)` in css to allow the `bkgImg` to be shown but nothing is working!

```
.customRound{
    background:none;
}   

.customRound > ul{
    background:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.customRound > ul > li{
    background-color:black;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    border-radius:25px;
}


.bkgImg {
    background-image: url("Images/PrettyPicture.png");
    background-size:cover;
}
```

So my question is how to prevent the default body background overriding the bkgImg set in the wrapping `<div>` ?? How do I get "no" background on my `<customRound>` and `<ul>` ??

Comment: try giving `display: inline-block` to anchor link

Comment: You mean the link inside the list? I don't think that's causing the background image to be overwritten because if I remove the `customRound` class it works totally fine.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, you mean to the parent class, my `customRound` class - yes, this works! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background: transparent` to allow a parent background to be seen behind an element.

Comment: I considered that but does transparency work on all browsers?! I was under the impression this might give me trouble down the line so was looking for a way to just "turn off" the background

Comment: `rgba()` is supported from  IE9 up.

Comment: I've tried adding `background: rgba(0,0,0,0)` to both the class and the class > ul, but it doesn't work. `background: transparent` on both doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'z-index' i.e lower z-index value on the div with no class and higher z-index value on .customRound.

Comment: 1) I can't set a z-index on the div with no class unless I assign some css selector, I don't want to do it in-line, and 2) the items are showing up fine so z-index is not the issue. If I set the background image to a higher z-index then it'll just hide the child `div` elements...

Comment: You can apply the CSS as below.

.bkgImg div:eq(0) /*Which affects the first child*/
{z-index: 9;}

.bkgImg div.customRound{
   z-index: 999;
}